# How can I start a daemon?

Tags: services

How can I start a daemon process with the use of `start-stop-daemon`? When I run:

```
start-stop-daemon --stop  --name NetworkManager
```

...it stops just fine. However, when I try to start it up it fails:

```
start-stop-daemon --start  --name NetworkManager

start-stop-daemon: --start needs --exec or --startas

start-stop-daemon --exec --startas /etc/init.d/network-manager --name NetworkManager

start-stop-daemon: need one of --start or --stop or --status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with :

```
start-stop-daemon --start --startas /etc/init.d/network-manager --name NetworkManager
```

Comment: Perfect !  i would of never guessed.  thank you